# Not to log to catalina.out

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have the following logging.properties configuration:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /mnt/asd/tomcat_logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /mnt/asd/tomcat_logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /mnt/asd/tomcat_logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = /mnt/asd/tomcat_logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
```

In the folder /mnt/asd/tomcat_logs there are the following files:

- catalina.2010-08-06.log
- host-manager.2010-08-06.log
- localhost.2010-08-06.log
- manager.2010-08-06.log

But in the **/etc/tomcat/tomcat/log** folder there is also **catalina.out** file. How can I change the path of the file to /mnt/asd/tomcat_logs??

Answer (score 6):

Edit **conf/logging.properties** and change:

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

By

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Answer (score 3):

Found answer here: http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-stop-logging-to-catalina-out-with-tomcat-6-0

Comment: Note: the link above shows how to **disable** logging to `catalina.out`.

Answer (score 2):

Above approaches are correct, but rather than changing existing sh files, please create new "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh" file and add this entry:

```
export CATALINA_OUT="/new/path/to/catalina.out"
```

Do not forget to `chmod +x "$CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh"`.

For Windows use its `setenv.bat` counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

you must edit "$CATALINA_BASE"/bin/catalina.sh file and find CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out  and replace with new path .

restart tomcta and enjoy it .

Comment: See David Vit's answer for a more proper way of setting up this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You might be overriding the logging.properties file somewhere, So you must check for :

```
############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```