# Turn off logging to catalina.out

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, tomcat7

I've configured log4j to log to different files and I want tomcat to completely stop logging to catalina.out.
It seems impossible.

tried

[Not to log to catalina.out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424515/not-to-log-to-catalina-out)

and

https://serverfault.com/questions/476647/why-does-tomcat7-log-into-both-catalina-out-and-catalina-yyyy-mm-dd-log

And they didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: configured to log to /dev/null

Comment: how exactly ? I cant stop tomcat from logging, tried everything in conf/logging.properties

Answer (score 0):

Here below an example working with log4j

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Solution:
You can disable log to catalina.out within your application with few lines of code.

```
    ConsoleAppender console = new ConsoleAppender(); 
    String PATTERN = "%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %l %m%n";
    console.setLayout(new PatternLayout(PATTERN)); 
    console.setThreshold(Level.OFF);  // disable log to console (catalina.out)
    console.activateOptions();
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(console);
    RollingFileAppender rfa = new RollingFileAppender(); // set log to another file
    rfa.setName(warName);
    rfa.setImmediateFlush(true);
    rfa.setFile(System.getProperty("catalina.home") + "/logs/"+warName+".log");
    rfa.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %l %m%n"));
    rfa.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
    rfa.setAppend(true);
    rfa.setMaxFileSize("10MB");
    rfa.setMaxBackupIndex(50);
    rfa.activateOptions();
    Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(rfa);
    // at this point you can log with:
    Logger log = Logger.getRootLogger();
    log.debug("------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-------------");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following to disable writing to `catalina.out` :

1. Locate and Edit File: {CATALINA_BASE}/bin/catalina.sh

Locate "**CATALINA_OUT**" and replace the path with "**/dev/null**":

```
 CATALINA_OUT="$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out // Original Location
 CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null // replace path to /dev/null
```