# Tomcat disable catalina.out

Tags: tomcat8

In our web application deployed on tomcat, `catalina.out` file keeps growing (it grows in GB's).

So to disable it I found solution where I set `CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null`.
This worked as expected but we also use `kill -3 <PID>` command to capture Thread Dump whenever it requires.

This thread dump gets written into `catalina.out` file but now I have disabled `catalina.out` so I cannot see thread dump.

How can I get thread dump?

Since it is a production system therefore we are using JRE and not JDK otherwise we would have used jmap/jcmd/jstack commands to capture thread dump.

So, I would like, tomcat should stop creating `catalina.out` file or do not write `log4j` statements in it. And if it is disabled then how to get thread dump?

Comment: [You can disable log to catalina.out within your application with few lines of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281779/724039)  ?

Comment: Thanks Luuk, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution which I was looking for. I added below lines of statement in `tomcat/bin/startup.sh` file

```
export CATALINA_OUT=/dev/null
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=thread_dump.log"
```

`CATALINA_OUT` set to /dev/null will stop writing log statements in `catalina.out` log.

`JAVA_OPTS` `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=thread_dump.log` configurations is used to write thread dump statements generated using `kill –3 <PID>` command. It will also print JVM-related configuration being used.

I hope this will help someone.