# What is the main reason of a *.war file can't create anything at Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, war, tomcat9

I'm trying to use Oxalis, which is an API for sending and receiving UBL document via specific AS2 protocol. Installation guide can be found at https://github.com/difi/oxalis. Pre-requiremetns are Java 1.8, Maven 3.x and Tomcat 9.0. My problem is, at end of instructions of installation guide, i obtain a oxalis.war file (Also i've already tried to do other guide, you can see at http://mmnclk.com/peppol-access-point-oxalis). After that i copy to the webapps folder of Tomcat. But after when i start Tomcat, being created oxalis folder. And I expect to see different files in this folder but only I have META_INF and WEB_INF folders. What could be the main reason of this? If you guys can help me, I would be very pleased.

Edit: After @slawek_k post, I got the following output.

```
c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps>jar tvf oxalis.war
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 META-INF/
   500 Mon Dec 25 12:34:16 GMT+03:00 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/inbound
/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/inbound
/guice/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/inbound
/servlet/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/
  1831 Mon Dec 25 12:34:14 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/logback-oxalis-inbound
.xml
  1614 Mon Dec 25 12:34:16 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/inbound
/guice/OxalisInboundModule.class
   762 Mon Dec 25 12:34:16 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/inbound
/OxalisGuiceContextListener.class
  1503 Mon Dec 25 12:34:16 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/inbound
/servlet/HomeServlet.class
  2912 Mon Dec 25 12:34:16 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/no/difi/oxalis/inbound
/servlet/StatusServlet.class
    87 Mon Dec 25 12:34:14 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/classes/reference.conf
  4467 Mon Dec 18 15:29:46 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
102291 Mon Dec 18 15:30:34 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/bcmail-jdk15on-1.56.jar
685403 Mon Dec 18 15:30:44 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar
3448507 Mon Dec 18 15:30:54 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar
 49742 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/brave-4.0.6.jar
132977 Mon Dec 18 15:31:12 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/brave-core-4.0.6.jar
 10803 Mon Dec 18 15:31:22 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/brave-http-4.0.6.jar
  9915 Mon Dec 18 15:31:22 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/brave-web-servlet-filter-4
.0.6.jar
 80593 Mon Dec 18 15:31:10 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/commons-certvalidator-2.1.
0.jar
 17576 Mon Dec 18 15:31:10 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/commons-sbdh-0.9.4.jar
219554 Mon Dec 18 15:30:34 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/config-1.2.1.jar
2521113 Mon Dec 18 15:30:46 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/guava-21.0.jar
674028 Mon Dec 18 15:30:42 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/guice-4.1.0.jar
 81866 Mon Dec 18 15:31:10 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/guice-multibindings-4.1.0.
jar
 82179 Mon Dec 18 15:30:48 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/guice-servlet-4.1.0.jar
  2497 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-1.jar
 16516 Mon Dec 18 15:31:10 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.24.jar
633290 Mon Dec 18 15:31:22 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-2.9.7.jar
310442 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.1.jar
473113 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.2.1.jar
521157 Mon Dec 18 15:31:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.7.jar
 28773 Mon Dec 25 12:34:02 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/oxalis-api-4.0.0-RC2.jar
 79435 Mon Dec 25 12:34:14 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/oxalis-as2-4.0.0-RC2.jar
 74910 Mon Dec 25 12:34:12 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/oxalis-commons-4.0.0-RC2.j
ar
 32676 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/peppol-common-0.9.7.jar
224405 Mon Dec 18 15:31:10 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/peppol-evidence-0.9.7.jar
  4623 Mon Dec 18 15:30:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/peppol-mode-0.9.7.jar
 29853 Mon Dec 18 15:31:10 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/peppol-sbdh-0.9.7.jar
 24227 Mon Dec 18 15:31:10 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/peppol-security-0.9.7.jar
 41205 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar
164895 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/zipkin-1.19.2.jar
 30687 Mon Dec 18 15:29:32 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/zipkin-reporter-0.6.12.jar

 10986 Mon Dec 18 15:31:12 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/lib/zipkin-sender-urlconnectio
n-0.6.12.jar
  2275 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 WEB-INF/web.xml
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 META-INF/maven/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 META-INF/maven/no.difi.oxalis/
     0 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 META-INF/maven/no.difi.oxalis/oxalis-i
nbound/
  6196 Wed Mar 01 05:17:12 GMT+03:00 2017 META-INF/maven/no.difi.oxalis/oxalis-i
nbound/pom.xml
   128 Mon Dec 25 12:34:18 GMT+03:00 2017 META-INF/maven/no.difi.oxalis/oxalis-i
nbound/pom.properties
```

Edit 2:I had some errors and i fixed it. But in my catalina.log record if u look at last 2 line what should i do ?

```
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 25 2017 21:08:02 UTC
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.2.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;E:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\client_2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\maven\bin;.]
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-443"]
INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1482 ms
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.2
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\oxalis.war]
INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

At the same time, as you can see in following link, i can't start application under the /oxalis folder under the manager application of Tomcat. When i tried to start just refresh the page.

[Manager App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdTpF.png)

Note 1: This is my oxalis folder in the webapps folder.(This created after i put oxalis.war folder into the webapps)

[My Oxalis Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtZnQ.png)

Edit 3: When start Tomcat server i got this output.

[Tomcat Start Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYnJw.png)

Comment: The reason is probably that your war doesn't contain anything else. Why do you think it should contain anything else? What else do you expect to contain, and why? Why do you even care about that directory and don't test if the app behaved the way it should?

Comment: Because according to installation guide, after follow instructions,I should have seen some files (e.g. status, as2). But i didn't see anything. I've tried to contact with contributer but i didn't any response from him.

Comment: Check the tomcat logs for any error.

Comment: I checked my log files. And i had punctuation error in my oxalis.conf folder i solved this. By the way, in localhost-access.log, i get 404 not found when server requests GET /oxalis HTTP/1.1".

Answer (score 0):

Check the environment of the user who has created the .war file. Especially the permission right. 
Control the contents of the .war file.

```
jar tvf yourfile.war
```

The permissions right of all files should match with the tomcat environment. 
Check the permission of your running tomcat ( tomcat or root ) environment and compare it with the one of your .war file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. After did this i got "Error: Could not find or load main class jar" message. I've looked for this problem and i found some solutions for that, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed reply. I've edited my message with output of command.

Comment: By the way, i want to make a better explanation. I download this project from GitHub and after that i build with mvn clean install via cmd (and alsı i tried over Linux). And i obtain an oxalis.war file. After that i put this file into Tomcat webapps folder and after that create a directory which is oxalis file. According to the installation guide i can access https://localhost/oxalis/status but when i try to reach this url, i'm getting error everytime. And when i look at the oxalis folder, i see only two directories (WEB_INF and META INF). But i guess i should see other files.

Comment: This problem is known. See for example 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204124/how-to-fix-jars-that-were-scanned-but-no-tlds-were-found-in-them-in-tomcat-9

Comment: If I understood corectly, your war-file is not deployed completly and is not running. Try to restart the application and watch the messages. If your application is not started you should see  any messages in catalina.out when you deploy your application..
Can you post the catalina.log if you copy the oxalis.war.

Comment: I don't have catalina.out. I tried this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424515/not-to-log-to-catalina-out) and nothing happened. But i edit my first post and you can see what happened about oxalis when start tomcat.

Comment: In your logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties set 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost‌​].level = FINE
and/or
org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.level = FINE 
to see more in catalina.log. You can find where is your catalina.log in the scripts setenv.sh or catalina.sh ( under Windows similar name but another suffix ). After you set new debug level , restart tomcat. You should see the jars without tlds. Post these log

Comment: @KıvançEren did you run this on windows using tomcat alongside?